# Nginx configuration proxy, access returns 301？

Tags: linux, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

This is the nginx configuration：

```
  location /debug {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:32339/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }
```

Expected visits http://127.0.0.1:80/debug/a/b Proxy to http://127.0.0.1:32339/a/b

The actual server returned 301 redirects to http://127.0.0.1:80/a/b.

I don't want him to do this, it should act as an agent http://127.0.0.1:32339/a/b
[image]

Configure `proxy_ pass http://127.0.0.1:32339/;` Remove the end, it will no longer redirect, but `/debug` still exists

```
  location /debug {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:32339;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }
```

nginx version 1.23.3

Please help me, thanks;

I have tried this configuration before, but the result is still the same

```
  location /debug/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:32339;
    rewrite /debug/(.*) /$1 break;
  }
```

Using curl to execute results

```
[root@node1 conf.d]# curl --location http://127.0.0.1:80/debug/a/b
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.23.3</center>
</body>
</html>
[root@node1 conf.d]#
```

Comment: What is the result of `curl --location http://127.0.0.1:80/debug/a/b`? Could you please update the question with the result?

Comment: @Andromeda Okay, I updated it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
 location ~ ^/debug(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:32339$1;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }
```

Comment: This configuration can be used. But I don't understand why there is a 301 redirect?

Comment: It might be coming from the upstream server.